# Functions taking iterables: peaks, compress, and skipper

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I am just testing out a few small functions for learning purposes:

```
def peaks(iterable):
    # returns a list of int for those values in the iterable that are bigger
    # than the value preceding and following them.
    itr = iter(iterable)
    peak =[]
    curr = next(itr)
    last = next(itr)
    try:
        while True:
            first = curr
            curr = last
            last = next(itr)
            if curr > first and curr > last:
                peak.append(curr)
    except:
        pass    
    return peak



def compress(v_iterable,b_iterable):
    #takes two iterables as parameters: it produces every value from the first iterable that
    # has its equivalent position in the second iterable representing what Python would consider
    # a True value. Terminate the iteration when either iterable terminates
    mega_it = dict(zip(v_iterable, b_iterable))
    for nxt in sorted(mega_it):
        if mega_it[nxt]:
            yield nxt


def skipper(iterable,n=0):
    #akes one iterable and one int (whose default value is 0) as parameters: it produces values from
    # the iterable, starting at the first one, skipping the number of values specified by the int
    #(skipping 0 means producing every value from the iterable)
    itr = iter(iterable)
    yield next(itr)
    while True:
        for i in range(n):
            skipped = next(itr)
        yield next(itr)
```

I feel like my codes are lengthy for the kind of work it does. Is there a way to make my functions cleaner or smaller?

Comment: Could you please split this question into several questions?

Comment: @200_success - I split the question into functions and classes. This one focuses on functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comments are good, but they should all be written as docstrings instead.

When working with iterators, [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) are your friend.  `peaks()` works with three iterators, so [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is useful.

Since the function accepts an iterable, it seems fitting that it should be a generator rather than returning a list.

Python supports double-ended inequalities.

```
from itertools import tee

def peaks(iterable):
    """Generates values in the iterable that are greater than the value
    preceding and following them."""
    before, this, after = tee(iter(iterable), 3)
    next(this)
    next(after)
    next(after)
    for prev, curr, succ in zip(before, this, after):
        if prev < curr > succ:
            yield curr
```

If you wanted to keep the old interface, which returns a list, then a list comprehension would be a good way to write it.

```
def peaks(iterable):
    """Returns a list of values in the iterable that are greater than the
    preceding and following value."""
    xs, ys, zs = tee(iter(iterable), 3)
    next(ys)
    next(zs)
    next(zs)
    return [y for (x, y, z) in zip(xs, ys, zs) if x < y > z]
```

---

I find your `compress()` weird, in that it sorts the results.

You can implement the function using just a generator expression.

```
def compress(values, incl_excl):
    """Keeping only values whose corresponding entry in incl_excl is true,
    generates the sorted filtered list."""
    yield from sorted(val for val, include in zip(values, incl_excl) if include)
```

---

In `skipper()`, the two occurrences of `yield next(itr)` should be combined.

```
def skipper(iterable, n=0):
    """Generator that yields the first element, then skips n values between
    results, until the input is exhausted."""
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        yield next(iterable)
        for _ in range(n):
            next(iterable)
```

Comment: @ 200_success - sorry this might seem unrelated but when I make the changes to the function, and try to do `print(peaks([0,1,-1,3,8,4,3,5,4,3,8]))` it keeps giving me the memory location `<generator object peaks at 0x0000000002935558>` instead of `[1, 8, 5]`.

Comment: That's what I meant by "it should be a generator rather than returning a list." If you want to display a list, then write `print(list(peaks([0,1,-1,…])))`.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to make the function cleaner without making it a generator? I ask as the program should pass a pre-designed batch test which might just have `print(peaks([0,1,-1,3,8,4,3,5,4,3,8]))` written.

Comment: Sure. I'd use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

`skipper`'s functionality is covered by [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
def skipper(iterable,n=0):
    return itertools.islice(iterable, 0, None, n+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to note that `peaks` could've been implemented with just two iterators.  Somewhere along these lines:

```
def peaks(iterable):
    state = False
    for previous, following in zip(iterable, iterable[1:]):
        if state and previous > following:
            yield previous
        state = previous < following
```

Of course it's up to you to replace `iterable[1:]` with an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Code presented by 200_success avoids the problem, but I think it should be pointed out that you are ignoring all errors. A catch-all is never a good idea, it hides problems. You should use:

```
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Variables that are assigned to but never used are not useful. Variable `_` is often considered an anonymous variable, good for replacing `i`. And `skipped` can be just skipped (pun).

```
for i in range(n):
    skipped = next(itr)

for _ in range(n):
    next(itr)
```

Alternative implementation of skipper. I would recommend asserting (checking) if arguments are sane, negative `n` would lead to weird unexpected results.

```
def skipper(iterable, n=0):
    assert n >= 0
    return (a for i,a in enumerate(iterable) if i%(n+1) == 0)
```